# Weird sum that is almost definitely not $\sqrt 2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, decimal-expansion

I have not the ability to compute more than four digits of

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 H_n^{(\ln n)}}$$

$H_n^{(m)} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^m}$ is the [generalized harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalized_harmonic_numbers).

I know this is the weirdest sum and it offers me no actual interest.  All I know is that the decimal number starts off as $1.414...$ and I want to settle my mind that it is not actually $\sqrt 2$. That would be crazy. I have no reason to expect it. I just want some confirmation.

My calculations were from Desmos here https://www.desmos.com/calculator/helb1dgf1g.

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^n{n^{-\ln(k)}}=\sum_{k=1}^n{k^{-\ln(n)}}$. Is a pretty weird property. Not sure if it's helpful but this $H_n^{(\ln n)}$ has ... weird properties.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you considered using any extrapolation techniques to estimate a sum for the series? Compute for e.g. $n=100, n=316, n=1000, n=3162, n=10000$ or for $n=1000, n=2000, n=3000, \ldots$ or something similar, and try and fit appropriately. Since $H_n^{(\ln n)}\in O(1)$ one would expect the partial sums to satisfy $S_n=S-\frac{C}{n}+o(n^{-1})$, where $S$ is the value of the infinite sum, and you could extrapolate using this to get a (probably) better estimate for $S$.

Comment: One thing is clear, if this thing does converge to $\sqrt{2}$, it does so VERY slowly. At 10000 terms I get 1.41404032445, at 20000 terms I get 1.41409025035, and $\sqrt{2}$ is 1.41421356237.

Comment: Just throwing an idea at the wall here... is it possible for us to square it? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813684/square-of-a-series

Comment: @OscarLanzi Do you mean $k^2$ or $k$ in your denominator?

Comment: @steven someday MSE will leave the dark ages and make comments editable by their owners.  Until then, I copy/delete/paste to get another chance.

Comment: Note that if you truncate after $k$ terms, a comparison with the $1/n^2$ series reveals that the sum of the truncated terms is less than $1/k$.  (An earlier version of this comment had to be deleted because I was not aware of the nonexponential use of the superscript.)

Comment: @Mason: That's not a weird property, it's just a transformation of the summand that has nothing to do with the summation: $n^{-\ln k}=\mathrm e^{-\ln k\ln n}=k^{-\ln n}$.

Comment: Note that the comments by AlexanderJ93 and @OscarLanzi above together imply that $\sqrt2$ won't be reached, as the sum is more than $1/20000$ from $\sqrt2$ after the first $20000$ terms.

Comment: @joriki if this is proof, then you can make it an answer.

Comment: I would guess using extrapolation that this probably converges to about $1.414140218$ rather than $\sqrt 2 \approx 1.414213562$

Answer (score 4):

After interpolation by $H_n^{(s)}=\zeta(s)-\zeta(s,n+1)$ using [Hurwitz zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function), one might apply accelerated summation methods, such as [Abel–Plana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula) or (discrete) [Euler–Maclaurin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula).

The latter is implemented in [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/)'s `sumnum` command. The computation of $\zeta(s,a)$ using out-of-the-box `zetahurwitz` runs *too slow* for large values of $a$. A working solution is the asymptotics $$\zeta(s+1,a)\underset{a\to\infty}{\phantom{\big[}\asymp\phantom{\big]}}\frac1s\sum_{n=0}^{(\infty)}\binom{-s}{n}\frac{B_n}{a^{n+s}}.$$

I'm using $\sum_{n=0}^N$ at $a\geqslant M$, being too lazy to automate the choice of $M$ and $N$:

```
hzfasymp(s, a, N) = sum(n = 0, N, bernfrac(n) * binomial(-s, n) / a^n) / (s * a^s);
hzftuned(s, a, M, N) = if(a < M, zetahurwitz(s, a), hzfasymp(s - 1, a, N));
experiment(L, M, N) = sum(n = 1, L - 1, 1 / n^2 / sum(k = 1, n, k^(-log(n)))) \
 + sumnum(n = L, 1 / n^2 / (zeta(log(n)) - hzftuned(log(n), n + 1, M, N)));
```

so that `experiment(10, 10^5, 40)` produces more than $100$ correct digits, beginning with $$1.41414021781626730415277043584162320768489153366403329952828864498511\dots$$